# Centering the string with format and a variable

Tags: python, printing, format

I want to know how to write a string thats being centerd like so:

```
print("{0:^30s}".format("hello"))
```

but I want the 30 to be a variable instead, so If I send a "num=5" to a function it would be {0:^5s}, anyone knows the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A format specifier can itself contain replacement fields. You can use:

```
print("{0:^{num}s}".format("hello", num=30))
#                hello
```

Comment: But if I want to pass the num through a function, should I just write num in there? function(num) , and instead of num=30, num?

Comment: @Alex: You can use either `"{0:^{num}s}".format("hello", num=num)` or  `"{0:^{1}s}".format("hello", num)` if you have a variable `num`.

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach might be to use the `.center()` method:

```
string = "hello"
# num = 5 or below
num = function(num)
print(a.center(len(a) + num, ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

Get [termisize](https://pypi.org/project/termisize/) package

*Termisize* is a cross platform python module to fetch terminal size

Installing Termisize - `pip install termisize`

### Code

```
import termisize as t
name = "Terabyte"
known_as = "tbhaxor"

cols = t.get_cols()  # gets columns number i.e width of terminal
msg = "My Name is {0} and i am also known as {1}".format(name, known_as)
print( msg.center(cols) )
```